# Reference outside object in ajax callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

A simplified example:

```
// Let's create a new object
function MyObject() {
    //
}

// Add some method to this object
MyObject.prototype.myFunctionA = function() {
    //
}

// Another method
MyObject.prototype.myFunctionB = function(arg) {
    // AJAX GET request          
    $.get('script.php', { par : arg }, function(data) {

        // and here in the callback function    
        // I need to call MyObject.prototype.myFunctionA method!
        // but "this" references callback function so
        // I don't know how to access MyObject here

    });
}
```

I have explained my issue in the comments. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simplest:

```
// Let's create a new object
function MyObject() {
    //
}

// Add some method to this object
MyObject.prototype.myFunctionA = function() {
    //
}

// Another method
MyObject.prototype.myFunctionB = function(arg) {
    // AJAX GET request       
    var me = this;   
    $.get('script.php', { par : arg }, function(data) {
        // use me.something instead of this.something
    });
}
```

reusable (using scope trapping):

```
function createDelegate(obj, handler)
{
    return function() {
        handler.apply(obj, arguments);
    }
}
```

then

```
MyObject.prototype.myFunctionB = function(arg) {
    // AJAX GET request       
    var me = this;   
    $.get(
        'script.php', 
        { par : arg },
        createDelegate(this, function(data) {
        // use this.something
        })
    );
}
```

So, some code in relation to the comments below, createDelegate can also be used in a few different ways, one of which being:

```
function createDelegate(obj, handler)
{
    handler = handler || this;
    return function() {
        handler.apply(obj, arguments);
    }
}

Function.prototype.createDelegate = createDelegate;
```

this allows you to do things like:

```
var someObj = {a:1, b:function() {return this.a;}};
var scopedDelegateForCallback = someObj.b.createDelegate(whateverobj)
```

you can do tricks to get parent too, but that's too much for me to bother with atm.

or, you can do something like this:

```
function createDelegate(handler, obj)
{
    obj = obj || this;
    return function() {
        handler.apply(obj, arguments);
    }
}

Object.prototype.createDelegate = createDelegate;
```

and to use it:

```
someObj.createDelegate(someObj.b);
```

or maybe:

```
function createDelegateForMember(handlerName, obj)
{
    obj = obj || this;
    return function() {
        obj[handlerName].apply(obj, arguments);
    }
}

Object.prototype.createDelegate = createDelegateForMember;
```

then

```
someobj.createDelegate("b");
```

Comment: I like your `createDelegate` function, but I think it'd be even better if you moved the `obj` parameter to the end of the parameter list and made it optional, defaulting to `this`. That would save some code in the most common use-case.

Comment: if you're not specifying 'this', it's useless to use the createDelegate function :)

Comment: No, I meant something like this: `function createDelegate(handler, obj) { return function () { handler.apply(obj || this, arguments); }; }`.

And calling it like this: `$.get('script.php', { par: arg }, createDelegate(function (data) { /* do something */ }));`.

Comment: yeah, but 'this' in 'obj || this' refers to the 'this' of the function returned by createDelegate, which will be set to 'window' (as, for that matter, will the 'this' for createDelegate) - TBC for readability

Comment: i was going to post another comment, but will put it in my post, give me a minute :)

Answer (score 6):

you can assign "var self = this" in MyObject.prototype.myFunctionB before calling the $.get
then you can use the alias "self" inside the callback.

```
MyObject.prototype.myFunctionB = function(arg) {
    var self = this;

    $.get('script.php', { par : arg }, function(data) {
       alert(self);
    });
}
```

Comment: Clean and simple. Great answer!

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript functions "[close over](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)" variables in outer scopes, so you can do this:

```
// Another method
MyObject.prototype.myFunctionB = function(arg) {
    // Save `this` reference for use in callback.
    var that = this;

    // AJAX GET request
    $.get('script.php', { par : arg }, function(data) {

        // Now `that` holds the contents of the current `MyObject`.
        // So you can call other methods.
        that.myFunctionA();
        // ... etc ...

    });
}
```